# Simple question about stochastic differential

Tags: stochastic-calculus

What is the equivalent of product rule for stochastic differentials? I need it in the following case: Let $X_t$ be a process and $\alpha(t)$ a real function. What would be $d(\alpha(t)X_t)$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $\alpha(t)$ is of finite variation, then the product rule is the same as in ordinary calculus:

$$
d(\alpha(t)X_t) = \alpha(t) dX_t + X_t d\alpha(t).
$$

If you had $X_t$ and $Y_t$ as processes, you would get

$$
d(X_t Y_t) = X_t dY_t + Y_t dX_t + d [X,Y]_t.
$$

If $Y$ has finite variation, the last quadratic covariation term is zero.  The second equation is just applying Ito's Formula to $f(x,y) = xy$.

Comment: hi! can you give the non finite product rule also?

Comment: The second equation is the general product rule.